# How this expansion correlate with the normal formula of Taylor expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I usually see this kind of approximations in physics and I don't understand how it is correlate the taylor expansion formula. Consider the function $f(x)$ and now for $a<<1$ they write

$$f(x+a)= f(x) + f'(x)\cdot a + \frac{1}{2!}f''(x)\cdot a^2 + O(a^2)$$ now I don't understand how it is correlate to the familliar formula?
$$f(x+x_0)= f(x_0)+f'(x)\cdot (x-x_0)+ \frac{1}{2!}f''(x)\cdot(x-x_0)^2 + O(x^2)$$

why the first term is not $f(a)$? who is my $x_0$ in this case?

Comment: I think the second equation should have $f(x)$ instead of $f(x_0)$. I think the point here is that $x$ is some "large" number, and $x_0$ is a really small number. But also the notation is not optimal. We're now confusing the general expression of the function (usually denoted by $f(x)$) and a single value of the function.

Comment: according to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition  the first term I wrote in correct, and I am not sure what did you mean by saying "confusing" if you can explain in more details

Comment: The correct Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ near $x = x_0$ has the form
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) \cdot (x - x_0) + \frac{1}{2!} f''(x_0) \cdot (x - x_0)^2 + O((x-x_0)^3)
$$
The $x$ from the first formula is $x_0$, $a$ is $x - x_0$. $O(a^2)$ term is incorrect, but it should be either $O(a^3)$ or $o(a^2)$ depending on existence of higher derivatives of $f(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $h(t) = f(x+t)$ and write its Taylor expansion around $t_0 = 0$:
$$
h(t) = h(0) + h'(0)t + \frac{1}{2}h''(0)t^2 + o(t^2).
$$

Evaluate at $a$ and you get
$$
f(x+a) = f(x) + af'(x) + \frac{1}{2}a^2f''(x) + o(a^2).
$$